# Why do I get a bad request (code 400) with HttpWebReponse?

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, webrequest

I am sending a simple json message to a WCF server application.

**Json message:**

```
{"Name":"Julian", "Id":123}
```

**Client side code:**

```
public string MakeRequest(string parameters)
{
        Console.WriteLine("parameters:" + parameters);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EndPoint);
        request.Method = Method.ToString();
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = ContentType;

        Console.WriteLine("request: " + request.Headers.ToString());

        if (PostData != null && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var bytes = ObjectToByteArray(PostData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Content length: " + request.ContentLength); 

            using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseValue = string.Empty;

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }

                // grab the response
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }

                return responseValue;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            string responseText;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(exception.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return responseText;
            }
        }

private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
{
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
         }
}
```

**Server side code:**

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "/postdata")]
    public Person PostData(Person data)
    {
        //Return new person with data inputted from json message
        return new Person()
        {
            Id = data.Id,
            Name = data.Name
        };
    }
```

**Server's Config file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

  <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Metadata">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/service1"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/service1" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Metadata">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>

    <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <webHttp />
          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**About the code:**

- (Client side) The input to the MakeRequest method is just the json data shown above.
- (Client side) The Uri being posted to is just "localhost:8732/service1/postdata" (yes including http:// just can't include it here as it counts as a link and I can only have two apparently)
- (Server side) The server code is an implementation of this solution I found at Code Project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec?fid=1614381&fr=1&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed#xx0xx

**What I've tried:**

- I've used Postman to POST a json message to the above uri and have received a response (for now it just returns a package with the same data) so I'm having a hard time finding any issues in the uri.
- I've validated the json package with JSONLint.
- I have added various try/catch blocks to get more error info but they all amount to protocol error/bad request error code 400.
- I have also smashed things in my mind (it's cheaper and less alarming for my flatmate)

**Current Output:**

I get a bad request response from the server with no data.

**Update 1:**

I must have been getting the data conversion order wrong. Before I:

- created Person object
- converted Person object to json
- passed json to MakeRequest method
- (in MakeRequest) created WebRequest converting json to byte array

The first if-statement of the MakeRequest() method (Client side) has been updated with a code segment that makes the request with the json *as is*. I now get a protocol violation error when write.Flush() executes:

**Updated client side code (MakeRequest method)**

```
if (PostData != null && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
    {
        //var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        //var bytes = ObjectToByteArray(PostData);
        //request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        //Console.WriteLine("Content length: " + request.ContentLength); 

        //using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        //{
        //    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        //}


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
```

**Update 2:**

The protocol violation error from the streamWriter.Flush() call was because I hadn't set the request.ContentLenth. I have now set the Content.Length to json.Length and I now get this error:

[image: System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable]

The image is a bit small but the error message reads:

```
"System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think** the problem was in the first lines of the try block. I attempt to read the response from the *request object* ... ehem ... Although I did try to read the response from the *response object* further down the damage was already done. I've included the working code below together with the commented out code that was causing the issue. I have marked the offending request.GetResponse() with **** as well as the correct response.GetResponseStream() which you'll be happy to hear, is now free to do its job.

Hope this saves someone a lot of time!

**All the relevant parts of the MakeRequest method:**

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EndPoint);
        request.Method = Method.ToString();
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = ContentType;


        Console.WriteLine("request: " + request.Headers.ToString());

        if (PostData != null && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("json length: " + json.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            request.ContentLength = json.Length;
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();             

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            // ****    FIRST READ USING request.GetResponse()    ****
            //var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            //using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            //{
            //    streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            //}

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseValue = string.Empty;

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }

                // grabs the response
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            //  ****    SECOND READ USING response.GetResponseStream()    ****
                            responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }
                return responseValue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read a stream to the end, you have to Seek it back to the beginning.

You can try this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
sr.ReadToEnd();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
sr.ReadToEnd(); // This should work now
```

Comment: Didn't fix the problem - got an exception something about Seek Operations not being supported by the stream? I do have a solution now though!